# problem with using datehour() function in DolphinDB

Tags: dolphindb

codes in GUI:

```sql
datehour(2018.09.03 8:30:00)
```

runtime error:

```sql
2020.12.09 17:14:24.420: executing code ...
Both arguments of 'pair' must be a scalar
```

why?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the function datehour(), the month, date, hour, minute and second in its parameter must contain two digits.
The correct code is shown as below:

```sql
datehour(2018.09.03 08:30:00)
```

And the result is:

```sql
2018.09.03T08
```